Who is the actor playing "Jack Stein" in "Death Wish 4: The Crackdown"?
Who is the actor playing "Jack Stein" in the movie Death Wish 4: The Crackdown (1987)?
I checked on IMDb and the credits at the end of the movie, but there's no information about the actor. He's the character with dark glasses. The other actors are Charles Bronson (Kersey), Michael Russo (D. Moreno), and Danny Trejo (Art Sanella).



I noticed that Jack Stein is listed as 'Unknown Actor 150-A' on the Cinemorgue Wiki. I find it surprising that the actor playing Jack Stein isn’t credited on IMDb or in the movie’s end credits. Have you considered posting this question on other forums or social media groups dedicated to classic action films? Someone there might have the answer.

If anyone has access to physical media like VHS or DVD releases of Death Wish 4, there might be additional credits or production notes that aren’t available online. Has anyone checked these sources?

I have a vhs and a dvd, and in both is not credited.
